# Acer Aspire no Post beep, no Bios splash screen (GPU issues?)

Tags: windows-7, boot, motherboard, bios, linux-mint

I have an Acer Aspire AX3400 desktop PC.

It originally came with Windows 7, But I dual booted it with Linux Mint 20.1.
After have used the computer for about a year, (It's from 2012 I think, I got it from a friend)
I tried to boot it up one morning and there was not Post beep/Bios splash screen, Fans turned on, Hd spun, but other then that, nothing. I turned it off and waited about a minute then pressed the power button again. This time nothing went wrong. booted into Linux Mint and it seemed fine.
However, the problem kept happening (strangely when I *restarted* the system this problem never occurred)

I took to always restarting and never shutting down the system. (That was maybe a mistake)
Anyway, I shut down the system to boot into Windows.
After that I couldn't get the system to boot back up.

I have tried:

Unplugging the computer and wait 30 minutes,

removing the motherboard battery and waiting 5 minutes,

resetting the bios using the bios reset jumper https://neosmart.net/wiki/reset-bios-cmos/#Method_2_Clear_the_jumper (Using method two)

I have tried every method I could think of.

Thank you for any help you provide.

UPDATE:

I think this might be a problem with the nvidia GPU, because the screen will randomly freeze when it's been running fine for a while. (Music I have playing will still play and I can still move the mouse, so probably not a CPU problem?) I've read that that if POST find a problem it will stop so maybe a problem with the GPU.

Note: I've switched out the hard drive with another on and still get problems. Sooo, not the HD

Comment: Boot from a bootable USB key and see if you can see the hard drive. It may have failed (8 or 9 years old according to your post)

Comment: If you're not getting POST beeps the issues are occurring BEFORE the system gets to that point. This usually means significant hardware faults, in this case likely due to age, I'd guess. Your computer may work, but it needs to be repaired.

Comment: @John: see update, I really don't see how my hard drive could have failed if I can boot.

Comment: @music2myear I would think that this might be a problem but I can now boot which lead me to think that maybe this was/is a software issue. do you know of any crash logs in the bios that I might be able to access? I did reset the bios with the reset jumper in the computer but it still wouldn't boot (see post (post not power on system check)) In case it is a hardware problem are the any places you would recommend me going to to get it checked?

Comment: HDD failures may affect different areas of the platter and may or may not affect booting. It could of course be another type of hardware failure.

Comment: @John I just looked at my hard drive from my linux mint OS and the diagnostic tool said there were eighteen back sectors. I don't really know if that is a lot but maybe my hd _is_ failing. I have a 500 GB hard drive with eighteen bad sectors, is that a lot? for 500 GB? I really have no idea.

Comment: Bad sectors means the drive is failing and should not be relied upon.

Comment: @John 
Really? I see. I was trying to pull up what I used to find the back sectors and can't seem to remember what I use :D I have been using the computer for about a week now and have noticed it has slowed down considerably. is this a symptom of hard drive failure? I can get a replacement drive so if this is the problem I would be almost happy. do you know of any tools I might use to diagnose this problem? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Most hard drive manufacturers have drive test apps. That is what I would use .

Comment: Sooo, I was wrong. It actually turned out to be the graphics card drivers. I was using the wrong one and that was messing up the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using open source drivers for an NVIDIA GPU. Apparently those two don't really go together to well :D
I have switched to the correct drivers and everything seems to be working. (Fingers crossed)

For any curious souls out the the GPU is a NVIDIA GeFource 8200 and the driver I was using was, xserver-xorg-video-nouvaeu version 1:1.0.16-1 and I am now using NVIDIA-340 version 340.0ubuntu5.20.04.2